# R Shiny unsource sourced files

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

One of the powers of **R / Shiny** is the posiblity to **"source" a other R file** in the R code. I am doing this dynamicly so in the end there are a lot of sourced files. So far so good.

```
FileToSource <- paste("Folder/",df$filename,".R", sep = "")
source(FileToSource, chdir=T)

unsource(......) ???
```

But at some point i want to clean up. I can delete variables etc. but can i **"unsource"** the previously **"sourced"** files ?

I have been looking for code of a way to do this but no luck up till now.

You can wonder **if it is nessesary to "unsource"** files but i like to **clean up** once in a while and this can be part of it. Less chance of **conflicting code** etc...

Suggestions ?

**Thanks in advance**, if i find a way i'll post it here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using a local environment. Let's say there is a file called `~/x.R` that contains one line `bb <- 10`. You can create a new environment

```
 envir <- new.env()
```

and then source the file in that environment by

```
 source('~/x.R',local=envir)
```

Then, you will be able to obtain the value of `bb` as `envir$bb`, and you wouldn't see `bb` in your Global Environment. Afterwards, you can delete the environment `envir` by setting `envir <- NULL` or something like that.

Comment: Hi Marat thanks, great way to go. I tested this with variables and functions and it is a nice way to manage sourcing and to prefend conflicting Code. I did this try in R: (see next answer -> better formatting)

Answer (score 2):

Great i did this test to find out if/how it works:

**A.R:**

```
xx <- function(){
 print("A print")
}
yy <- 11
```

**B.R:**

```
xx <- function(){
 print("B print")
}
yy <- 99
```

**Main.R:**

*(remove the # to get a Error : attempt to apply non-function)*

```
A <- new.env()
B <- new.env()
source("A.R", local=A)
source("B.R", local=B)
A$xx()
print(A$yy)
B$xx()
print(B$yy)
A <- NULL
#A$xx()
#print(A$yy)
B$xx()
print(B$yy)
B <- NULL
#A$xx()
#print(A$yy)
#B$xx()
#print(B$yy)
```

So in the end Main.R is

**EMPTY & CLEAN & TIDY**

<< just wat i wanted ! >>

THANKS @MARAT